# “Block if without end if” error in VBA following online tutorial

Tags: excel, vba

I'm newer to VBAs and Macros so I was following this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKV5seZmiBs, YouTube tutorial. For some reason I am stuck on a worksheet change code and it keeps saying  “Block if without end if”. I am not sure what I am missing in my code as I followed the tutorial exactly, can someone please look at this code and help? I would appreciate it!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:J18")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End
End If
If Sheet9.Range("B4").Value = False Then
If Sheet2.Range("N5").Value = Empty Then End
Dim UserRow As Long
Dim CurrentUser As String
Dim SharedFolder As String
Dim UserName As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentUser = Sheet9.Range("B8").Value 'Current User
SharedFolder = Sheet2.Range("N5").Value 'Shared Folder
For UserRow = 6 To 24
    If Sheet9.Range("D" & UserRow).Value = Empty Then GoTo NoUser
    UserName = Sheet9.Range("D" & UserRow).Value
    If CurrentUser = UserName Then GoTo NextUser
    If Dir(SharedFolder & "\" & UserName & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then fso.createfolder (SharedFolder & "\" & UserName & "\")
    Filename = SharedFolder & "\" & UserName & "\" & Target.Worksheet.Name & Target.Address & ".txt"
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(Filename)
    oFile.Writeline Target.Worksheet.Name & "," & Target.Address & "," & Target.Value
    oFile.Close
NextUser:
    Next UserRow
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set oFile = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Towards the top you have `End` there should be an `End If` after that

Comment: Even online tutorials can have syntax errors...

Comment: You need an online tutorial on proper indentation to help you easily spot the fix.